# Smooth swiffy image animation

Tags: html, flash, animation, google-swiffy

I'm using swiffy to convert flash banners to html & the problem is quite often I get pretty random results with tweening images. The problem is the animation isn't always smooth. I just created a set of banners, all of them are practically the same, made in exactly the same way & yet, this one:

http://midstraeti.is/mannrettindastofa/en/310x400-5.html

is ok, animation of the guy moving from bottom to top is smooth

but here:
http://midstraeti.is/mannrettindastofa/en/310x400-3old.html

the lady is moving up pixel by pixel, with no in-between values, hence the anim looks jagged/choppy. both banners are exactly the same. there's no filter on mc containing the image, allow smoothing is on. & this banner is the only one suffering the problem from the total set of 7.

any idea what's up? thanx in advance for all tips&tricks

*ps. this animation look smooth only in chrome, opera & safari. firefox/ie gives worse results with choppy 1px-1px movement.*

*ps2. doing some tests with jpg/png anims right now & animation comes up smooth only in safari...*

Comment: found a solution. adding 1px to the height of an image fixed the issue... guess there's something wrong with rounding up values @ swiffy

corrected file here: http://midstraeti.is/mannrettindastofa/en/310x400-3.html

Comment: another notice. this one: http://midstraeti.is/vr/disa.2/635x450.html animates smooth even in firefox/ie. i'm confused. what's the mystery here? :/